# malloc error: incorrect checksum

Tags: c, malloc

I am coding in C and receiving a malloc error with the error message:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe9d44026d8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. 
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The objective of my code is to store a generated maze into a 2D array from a string that stores the maze using the read() function. I am not having trouble reading the maze into the string but when I pass the string, number of rows, and number of columns as parameters to a function

What exactly does this malloc error mean? And how can I determine which part of my code is creating this error?

Comment: The tool Valgrind could tell you which code line modified  the freed memory.

Comment: Okay I'll have a look at it and see what I find. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of `malloc()` does additional checks not required by the C language standard. In this case, it seems to detect that some data in a memory block was modified **after** it was marked as free (by a call to `free()`). That's a bug in your program.

To find the culprit, use a memory debugging tool. For *nix systems, there is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). On windows, you can use [drmemory](http://drmemory.org/). These tools replace the memory management functions of your standard library and will notify you instantly about errors such as writing to some memory that was already `free()`d.

Comment: There is no call to 'free()' in my code though, when allocating memory to my 2D array of characters i call 'malloc()' to allocate memory to the rows first using 'sizeof(char*)' and then i call 'malloc()' to allocate memory to the columns using 'sizeof(char)' inside a while loop, iterating through each row.